# Retrieving file on sdcard with this path: "/document/primary:..."

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read contents of a CSS file, which is on my SDCARD.

I'm selecting the file from a action:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("text/css");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Here I grab the path:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Log.d("FilePicker", data.getData().toString());
                    editor.putString("custom_style_file", data.getData().getPath());
                    editor.commit();


                }
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    //Write your code if there's no result
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the following path `/document/primary:CustomCSS/myCustom.css`

Then i try to read the contents of the file with this function:

```
 public static String readFromSDcard(String path) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        //Get the text file
        File file = new File(sdcard, path);

        //Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }

        Log.d("Read from file", text.toString());
        return text.toString();
    }
```

The function returns nothing, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //You'll need to add proper error handling here
```

If you do so you will see why your function returns nothing.

For instance:

```
 text.append("IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
```

Your path:

```
 /document/primary:CustomCSS/myCustom.css
```

That is not a file syctem path but a content provider path.

So get a content resolver and then let it open an input stream for the file. After that you can use the usual code to read the contents.

Google for getContentResolver().openInputStream().

Comment: Do you have en example using the contect resolver? I can't seem to find any examples out there.

Comment: If you only copy that to your browsers google serach you get already several searches. Choose them and get the world of examples. You even will see it combined with `data.getData()`. Any more wishes?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the the read storage permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```